# Spring 3.2 JUnit4 Test Case passes when rolling back, but fails when not rolling back?

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit4

I have a Spring 3.2 application, using Hibernate, and some JUnit 4 test cases. I am using MySQL 5 as the database.

When writing test cases for a DAO class that rolls back, the test case passes. However, if I tell the test case not to roll back (@Rollback(false)), the test case fails. Because of this, I dont trust the validity of my test cases that pass when defaultRollback=true.

The test case in question is when deleting an object [Company], which has many [Team] objects. A [Team] object can also have many child [Team] objects.

When deleting the [Company], it cascades the delete to the  objects. When it deletes the [Team] objects, I didnt specify to cascade the delete to child [Team] objects, so there is a foreign key constraint violation exception being thrown by MySQL. The test case (when it is set to roll back), passes! However, it shouldnt, surely? If setting rollback to false on the test case, then it fails and moans about the MySQL contraint violation exception.

Any advice please? Why does the test case respond differently if @Rollback is set to true and then false?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a problem of flush or not flush. I think you hide some problem in Rollback mode, because the changes are not send to the datebase.

To profe  this add `em.flush()` at the end of your test in Rollback mode. If then the problem occures you can fix it.